# Could not initialize Start up controller. TaskManager not found

Tags: esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i have written a scheduled task which call an Api in sequence in wso2 ei 6.4.0. my task is :

```
<task xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
  name="GetMunicipalityAPIToken"
  class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
  group="synapse.simple.quartz">
<trigger interval="60"/>
<property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
  <test xmlns=""/>
</property>
<property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
         name="sequenceName"
         value="GetTokenFromMunicipalityService"/>
<property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
         name="injectTo"
         value="sequence"/>
</task>
```

and my sequence is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="GetTokenFromMunicipalityService" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="POST" uri-template="http://x.x.x.x/api/MunicipalityBill/connect/token"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
</sequence>
```

but when i run integrator.bat in wso2eiHome/bin I got this error : "Could not initialize Start up controller. TaskManager not found"  and the Api dont be called. Do i forget something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be caused when you do not have org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager defined in the server. Could you please check whether the following is added in the synapse.xml file located in the [EI_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/ directory

```
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <taskManager provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager"/>
</definitions>
```